# iOS 7 migration help - Runs in Simulator, but not on device -- app does not load

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

Disclaimer: I'm helping out on another developer's code (he didn't have the time and the customer wants it fixed quickly) and so I'm not totally familiar with this code.

So the app is built for iOS 6, is in the App Store, and runs great. Until you try opening it on a device running iOS 7 GM. You see the splash-screen for a moment, then it crashes completely. This is causing problems because none of our users can use the app anymore after updating.

I just got the source code and I have been trying to figure it out. It compiles fine, and even runs in the iOS 7 simulator. (Although, of course, the UI needs to be redesigned for iOS 7.)

Here's where it gets weird: when I run it on my iPhone 5 (iOS 7) from Xcode, the app hangs (just like with the App Store version, of course) -- but it's just so weird, considering that in runs in the Simulator.

Good news is that I have some runtime errors that might help to track down the problem. I ran a search that indicates it could be a missing connection in a xib file, but I didn't find one.

Here is the log. If it helps, I can also include the build warnings.

2013-09-20 20:16:55.455 myappname[2514:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2e3d0e8b 0x386ca6c7 0x2e3d0dcd 0x307d5feb 0x307d5eef 0x307d5e7f 0x30b53517 0x30b6373b 0x30c042f1 0x30b56533 0x307ddf43 0x307d9767 0x30b6b411 0x30b67ed5 0x30be7501 0x30be71a1 0x30c03685 0x30bcf53d 0x30c034bf 0x30b55f3d 0x30b55d19 0x30b55609 0x2ed32143 0x30b55495 0x30b62153 0x30b61bd3 0x30c43e13 0x30c8398b 0x30c83961 0x30c82abf 0x30c82663 0x30c8256f 0x5c4d7 0x30bc7425 0x30bc6e6b 0x30bc14b9 0x30b5bbe7 0x30b5aedd 0x30bc0ca1 0x3303c76d 0x3303c357 0x2e39b77f 0x2e39b71b 0x2e399ee7 0x2e304541 0x2e304323 0x30bbff43 0x30bbb1e5 0x5b485 0x38bc3ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

I really have no idea what is going on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: This is awfully non-specific. I mean, have you tried anything at all? Like, say, setting an exception breakpoint and seeing what's causing the layer to have NAN in its position?

Answer (score 0):

try to use preferredContentSize to define view size.